# The Mathematical Principles of Natural Philosophy

Tags: mathematics, newton

Please, advise a good review of Isaac Newton's work "The Mathematical Principles of Natural Philosophy" with a detailed analysis of his mathematical ideas. Smth about 20-25 pages.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophi%C3%A6_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica too short to serve your purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your requirements are contradictive: there CANNOT BE a "detailed analysis"
of mathematical ideas of all of Principia in 25-30 pages!

One of the best reviews covering all three books of Principia that I know is the Guide to Newton's Principia by I. Bernard Cohen. It is attached to the new translation of Principia itself, U. of California press, 1999. The Guide is 370 pages long.

There is also a book of S. Chandrasekhar, Newton's Principia for the common reader, 
[https://www.amazon.com/Newtons-Principia-Common-Reader-Chandrasekhar/dp/019852675X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019852675X)
but it covers only Book I. It is about 600 pages, and does not even completely cover Book I. The author, a Nobel prize winner astronomer and mathematician goes more in depth than Cohen.

A very short and popular account of SOME principal results of Book I is contained in
the book of V. I. Arnold, Huygens and Barrow, Newton and Hooke. The length of the part describing Principia is about as you request but of course he analyses only 2 or 3 main results in it. It is written by a famous mathematician but oriented at beginner mathematicians.

Comment: I meant that I would like to see the review primarily for mathematicians, not historians

Comment: All books I cited are written primarily for mathematicians. The best one can do in 20-30 pages is Arnold, which covers a small part of Book I.